# Are rank 1 projective modules over domains isomorphic to ideals of R?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, integral-domain, projective-module

This is probably just a stupid question about modules, but I'm having trouble proving the following, if it's true:

> Let $R$ be a domain and $M$ a rank $1$ projective module over $R$ (i.e. $\dim_K(K \otimes_R M) = 1$, where $K = \mathrm{Frac}(R))$. Then $M \cong I$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$.

The reason I would even suspect this is the proof I'm following to show projective modules over a Dedekind domain are sums of ideals assumes for the base case the above fact, in the case $R$ is Dedekind. But they only proved the opposite direction in the article, namely an ideal in *any* domain has rank 1, which leads me to suspect this is also a general fact.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's true. You can find a suitable map $M \to R$ giving $M$ as an ideal like this. Since $M$ is projective, it's torsion-free, so the map $M\to M\otimes_R K$ injects. When $M$ has rank one this gives $M$ as a submodule of $K$. If $M$ is finitely generated you can take a common denominator for the elements of a generating set (these elements thought of as lying in $K$). Then $M$ is contained in the module of fractions in $K$ with that denominator, and that module is isomorphic to $R$.

(You don't actually need to assume that $M$ is finitely generated, this follows from the hypothesis.)

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the torsion piece of the argument. This also shows that the statement is true for flat modules over domains!

Comment: @ProjModules 124: For flat modules I don't see how you can avoid the finite generation hypothesis for M. What do you say, anon? (I guess you get finite generation  in the projective case by using a "dual basis" , right?)

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed the part where finite generation can be avoided in the projective case. Is this hidden in the assumption $M$ is a summand of a free module?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit tricky. For flat modules, you need something more; eg, $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $M = \mathbb{Q}$ are a domain and flat, non-finitely generated module of rank one. For $M$ projective, Kaplansky's theorem says that $M$ is locally free on $R$, of rank one by assumption. I think if you take dual bases on a finite open cover of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ then you get a finite generating set for $M$. Google points out this MO thread which is more precise: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/178531/is-a-projective-module-of-constant-finite-rank-finitely-generated